# #ifdef SWIG : When does this conditional compilation is taken into consideration?

Tags: c++, wrapper, swig

I have in my header `sample.h` this :

```
#include <iostream>
#ifdef SWIG
int a = 0;
#endif
```

And in my `sample.i` this :

```
%module sample
%{
   #include "sample.h"

%}
#include "sample.h"
```

But, I don't see any difference between with and without the #ifdef SWIG...

Can you please let me know where and how I can find the difference, and what would it be??

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What difference would you want to see? You just create a global variable, you don't actually use it...

Comment: I expected to find it in the generated *.cxx file, for me it is `sample_wrap.cxx`. But I find nothing about the variable `a`... So maybe you mean by "Global variable that I don't see" that `a` gonna be created while SWIG compilation? So Where can I use it? Is it only between the `#ifdef #endif` ?

Comment: `#include` in C++ doesn't work like `include` in PHP. It doesn't actually put the code from one file into another, it just makes it visible for the compiler. Google "C++ preprocessor directives" for more help.

Comment: The point of using #ifdef SWIG is to put SWIG directives into the file that the compiler will not see.  They start with %.  `int a = 0;` is not a SWIG directive.  You will have to RTFM, at least chapter 1.7

Comment: What is the swig command you use to generate the _wrap.cxx file?

Answer (score 3):

Your .i file has an error. The last line should be `%include` not `#include`.  With this change, building your wrapper (I'm using Python) produces:

```
sample_wrap.cxx
sample_wrap.cxx(3200) : error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
sample_wrap.cxx(3211) : error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
```

This is because when compiled SWIG is not defined during `#include` and `a` does not exist in the resulting code.  When SWIG processes `%include` SWIG is defined and generates an interface for `a` which does not exist.

Removing the `#if` wrapper produces a correctly wrapped global variable:

```
>>> import sample
>>> sample.cvar.a
0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this: if you compile the code above in CMake, you can set the CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS for your interface file that are propagated to the attached header&c++ files. As such:

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(sample.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release")
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(sample.i PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DSWIG")
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(sample.i PROPERTIES CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DSWIG")
else(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release")
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(sample.i PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DSWIG")
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(sample.i PROPERTIES CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DSWIG")
endif()
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(sample python sample.i sample.cpp)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(Vector ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

In that case, the compilation is conditional (if you leave out the CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS part, there's no "a"), but if you want it it's there.

Comment: Aren't both `if` branches here same?

Comment: Nope. Functionally, the top-part adds the flags for the release build (e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`), the bottom part adds them for the debug build (e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`). The `else` conditional in parantheses is the same to indicate the CMAKE parser that this specific `else` corresponds to the `if` statement of the very same conditional.